# Stuck in ACPI and enabling HDA controller loop during installation of ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot

[image]

Guys I need dying help, I am not an expert in anyway,

I was encountering the same issue when I was trying to install it onto a USB drive which resulted in the USB thumb drive getting corrupted after several force termination and reformating of the drive

Then I switched to my hard drive to install alongside windows boot manager. Lo and behold I'm facing the same loop.i can't believe what is happening, I have so much project on the drive that hurt me a greatly if I am to loose them.

Please help me!!